# How to change 0.9M to float number Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, numbers, python-3.7

Is there a Python3 library that convert abrriviation of string number as : 10K, 0.2M, 32B etc. to float numbers?

exmple: 10K => 10000
0.9M=> 9000000 an so on.

If there isn't a library what is the efficient way to convernt those numbers?

**I tried to split the number from the letter but it only works with int and not double.

```
test_str = "9M"
temp = re.compile("([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)")
res = temp.match(test_str).groups()
```

More info: I get the number from the client that way and can't change it. It needed to be float for late calculations

Thanks !

Comment: What about adding the dot `.` to the characters allowed in the first group?

Comment: Something like `re.sub(r'(\d*\.?\d+)([KMGT])\b', lambda x: str(int(x.group(1))*dct_num[x.group(2)]), test_str)` where `dct_num` is a dictionary with `{'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000}`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> fact_dic = {'': 1, 'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000}
>>>
>>> def GetFloatFromFactor( input ):
...     m = re.search( r"^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([KM]?)$", input)
...     if m != None:
...         fval = float( m.group(1) ) * fact_dic[ m.group(2) ]
...         return fval
...     else:
...         return "no match"
...
>>> GetFloatFromFactor( '3K' )
3000.0
>>> GetFloatFromFactor( '12.4M' )
12400000.0
>>> GetFloatFromFactor( '098.281' )
98.281
```